# Web Scraping - sessionStorage distil_referrer

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find a good way to get into a website, but I have found a big issue.

What is returning is the header of the html file, where there are those lines of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_blocked.html?     Ref=/de/company/TI&amp;distil_RID=F180AC0A-ECA2-11E6-80AC- E678F530D985&amp;distil_TID=20170206193206" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function(window){
    try {
        if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
            sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
        }
    } catch (e){}
})(window);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ga625684.js" defer="defer"></script><style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#svevtdraftsrybvfradvq{display:none!important}</style></head>
<body>
<div id="distil_ident_block"> </div>


<div id="d__fFH" style="position: absolute; top: -5000px; left: -5000px;"><object id="d_dlg" classid="clsid:3050f819-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b" width="0px" height="0px"></object><span id="d__fF" style="font-family: ZWAdobeF,serif; font-size: 72px; visibility: hidden;">mmmmmmmmlli</span></div></body></html>
</script>
```

Is there a workaround to actually get the webpage?

For now i am trying to use Selenium without results

The code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("https://www.moneyhouse.ch/de/company/TI")
print driver.page_source
```

Comment: This **IS** the webpage, what more do you want??? BTW, there doesn't seem to be any relation between the title of the question and the body of the question.

Comment: @barakmanos actually that's not the webpage, this is the webpage i am looking for : https://www.moneyhouse.ch/de/company/TI, but when i try to use selenium to get the html it returns the code above

Comment: Well, you haven't shared any of your code, so it's a little impossible to tell what's going on (for example, how can we be so sure that this is indeed the URL that you pass to Selenium's web-driver?).

Comment: @barakmanos thank you for your time. I added the small snippet, because it's really 5 lines of code, as you can see I am using Firefox as webdriver